# Android Camera API Error 100 only on back camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to capture an image from the back camera using the Android Camera API.

I'm using [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html) code, 4. Tutorial: Using the camera API. It works when it uses the front camera. When I change `CAMERA_FACING_FRONT` to `CAMERA_FACING_BACK`, I get the Error 100 on

`camera.takePicture(null, null, new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));`

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S3. Anyone knows how to solve this? It has been asked a multiple times, but I haven't found a real solution anywhere.

Edit: [Full log until Error 100](http://pastebin.ca/3405564)

No exceptions in the program itself, error log:

```
03-19 01:57:43.069    2348-7984/? E/DatabaseUtils﹕ Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13140)
            at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2038)
            at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:607)
            at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
            at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
03-19 01:57:57.874    2348-2689/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 13376
03-19 01:57:59.734  18504-18557/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 18557 (pictureThread)
03-19 01:58:01.984  22720-22720/? E/ctxmgr﹕ [PowerConnectionProducer]Could not write powerInfo=Plug state: 2 BatteryLevel: 0.98, status=Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 7503, resolution=null}
03-19 01:58:07.239  18489-18489/com.example.luka.udpklijentandroid E/Camera﹕ Error 100
03-19 01:58:07.679  18607-18607/? E/TinyUCM﹕ 23.29: This output device support only one mic
03-19 01:58:07.679  18607-18607/? E/TinyUCM﹕ 24.32: This output device support only one mic
03-19 01:58:07.679  18607-18607/? E/TinyUCM﹕ 25.31: This output device support only one mic
03-19 01:58:07.679  18607-18607/? E/TinyUCM﹕ 26.40: This output device support only one mic
03-19 01:58:07.679  18607-18607/? E/TinyUCM﹕ 27.28: This output device support only one mic
03-19 01:58:07.679  18607-18607/? E/TinyUCM﹕ 28.35: This output device support only one mic
03-19 01:58:08.734    2348-2565/? E/AudioService﹕ Media server died.
03-19 01:58:08.734    2348-2565/? E/AudioService﹕ Media server started.
03-19 01:58:27.879    2348-2689/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 13377
```

Comment: Post the full error and stack trace (if any).

Comment: I think that the message at 01:57:59.734 is from your app. I would expect some more messages with tag DEBUG and level INFO after it. Did you post the log filtered for ERROR and higher?

Comment: I added a link to the full log in the post.